# Samsung GT-i9000 not detect USB connectivity in Windows 8

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, usb-drivers

I bought a new windows 8 laptop and tried to install the phone driver to recognize it, but can't succeed: I installed and restared the Samsung driver package and restared my computer, I also tried to search through the device Manager on the web but it didn't find anything (which is strange because in Windows 7 it did find). I also have a Windows 7 laptop and it works there...

What Should I do?

found the solution!

First check if u have normal google adb drivers, if no then download them , put your device in usb debugging mode (this settings location depends upon your android OS version)

Go to Devices and printers in control panel -> go to properties of your device ( device should be connected) -> Change settings -> update driver -> Let me pick driver from my pc -> adb interface -> (it will give u list of adb drivers on ur machice) if you find any Samsung driver there click on it and click next or finish. Else choose google adb interface driver and finish.

Your device should be working properly with proper drivers installed :)

Comment: Harel, thanks for sharing your experience! But on a Q&A site, the question goes in one box, while the answers go into separate boxes :) Could you please split your above post, and place the solution into an answer below? Otherwise, in lists it looks like a question without an answer, and many people will miss it. Thanks a lot!